# Jquery Button Inline

Tags: button, jquery-mobile, inline

i am new to anything JQuery and only know basic HTML codes.
So I was wondering what why

```
<div data-inline="true">
<a href="index.html" data-role="button">Cancel</a>
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Save</a>
</div>
```

did not work in my html file, even though I blatantly copied off the Jquery Documentation. The buttons did not appear side by side. Whereas when I tried

```
<a href="index.html" data-inline="true" data-role="button">Cancel</a>
<a href="index.html" data-inline="true" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Save</a>
```

and the buttons appeared side by side.

Does it have to do with my importing the script?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is all related, but you are using 1.0a3 in your example - the current version of jquery-mobile is 1.0a4.1 - it is possible this functionality was either added of fixed since a3.

Comment: nope i tried updating the thing so i dun think tt is the problem :D

Comment: I have the same problem, check my fiddle here: (http://jsfiddle.net/XaUfj/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it is probale that:

- the surrounding div causes that the anchors cannot be found by jQuery (or have different style)
- you miss data-inline="true" in the upper lines

Cheers

Comment: Sorry I dun really understand your second point. But I double check to see if my <div> </div> markers are alright

Comment: Does your first point means that there are too many <div> tags in the content section?

Answer (score 0):

i think you're referring to the [documents from here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-inline.html#/test/docs/buttons/index.html).

my guess is that you didn't include the css file. jqm-docs.css

```
<head><base href="http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-inline.html">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"> 
    <title>jQuery Mobile Docs - Buttons</title> 
    <link href="../../themes/default/" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link href="../_assets/css/jqm-docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/"></script>
    <script src="../docs/docs.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: :D thxs for answering promptly. but I was following the standard boiler page provided by jquery :D http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html

Comment: And if I am guessing correctly, you are downloaded the Jquery files? I am referring to their website instead